Solving a coupled augmented matrix equation.
We have already seen the Gaussian elimination method to solve a system of linear equations in augmented form. Now, I am trying to transform the followed coupled augmented matrix equation using elementary row operations:
$ \left( \begin{array}{ccc|ccc|ccc} 
1 & 4 & 1 & 1 & -2 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 5 & 1 & 3 & -1 & 2 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\
5 & 5 & 4 & 2 & 1 & 3 & 0 & 0 & 1\end{array}\right) $
to the form
$ \left( \begin{array}{ccc|ccc|ccc} 
1 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & * & * & * \\ 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & * & * & * \\
0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 1 & * & * & *\end{array}\right) $.

Where are you having trouble?

While transforming the first two matrices to two identity matrices in coupled form.

I don't understand what means "coupled"? What exactly is the equation you are trying to solve?

Means handling the first two matrices together, we shouldn't uncouple the above in two augmented forms, otherwise it does not give the desired result.

Sorry, I still don't know what "handling the first two matrices together" means. Can you explain it in terms of some matrix equations you are trying to solve? I don't see how you can do the same row operations to the one matrix as to the other and hope to bring both of them to echelon form.
